# CVODE Warning: Internal t = *** and h = 2.09813e-13 are such that t + h = t on the next step. The solver will continue anyway

Tags: finite-difference

I have a system to simulate the bubble evolution at different temperature conditions. I used `CVODE_DENSE` algorithm to solve the ODEs and get the bubble size and concentration. But the code was halted as the above warning shows up.

I tested at different temperatures, like 573 K and 773 K. The code was halted at 573 K at around 129 steps, but it was halted at 773 K at around 91 steps. Any ideas for further debug this code would be very appreciated.

Comment: What length of time do you want to run your simulations to? If the time step is 2e-13, that is a very very small time step if you try to make it further than a few nanoseconds...

Comment: In the Slack channel I mentioned you should [go through the steps of the FAQ to debug the model](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/basics/faq/#faq_stability). What things did you try?

Comment: The warning is telling you that $t$ and $t+h$ are equal up to double precision.  This could be because you asked for the solution over a tiny interval of time starting at a time that is non-zero, but its more likely that you have an extremely stiff system of equations with a method not designed for stiff systems and the solver is forced to take tiny steps because of the stiffness.  Which of the methods that CVODE supports are you using?

Comment: It would help if you could describe your system of equations in more detail and also describe the parameters that you used with CVODE.

Comment: "its more likely that you have an extremely stiff system of equations with a method not designed for stiff systems and the solver is forced to take tiny steps because of the stiffness" I wouldn't say that's likely. Given the number of people I see this happen to daily, for most people it's not a solver issue but an issue with how they wrote `f`, so I would almost certainly tell people to check their code first before thinking it's something to do with the solver.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas: Nothing in that quote says the solver is to blame, rather the stiffness of the user-provided function.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth The length of time I want to run for my simulation is in days. My understanding for the CVODE is that it is the variable time step method based on the tolerance and also the solution, and I didn't set the time step in the code.

Comment: @Chris Rackauckas Thank you for your response in the slack channel, after that I have tested the code using lower tolerance, like rtol=1e-10 and abtol=1e-12, and even to 1e-40. But the warnings are still there. When using the lower tolerance, the warning shows up at the early step, like 37 steps (didn't see warning in the high tolerant cases), but the code would still run until it halted at more than 1000 steps (this is longer than that in the high tolerant cases, in which the code is halted at less than 200 steps).

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thank you for your comments, the CVODE method that I used is from the Sundials CVODE, and used the linear Dense solver. I have tried to use Band before, but it fails when running for large systems, that's why I changed it to the dense solver.

Comment: @BrianBorchers The parameters that I used are in the following:                                                          cvode_mem = CVodeCreate(CV_BDF,CV_NEWTON); data = (UserData) malloc(sizeof *data); loadData(data); flag = CVodeSetUserData(cvode_mem, data); flag = CVodeInit(cvode_mem, f, T0, y0); flag = CVodeSStolerances(cvode_mem,RTOL,ATOL); flag = CVDense(cvode_mem, neq); flag = CVodeSetMaxNumSteps(cvode_mem, mxsteps); flag = CVode(cvode_mem, tout, y0, &t, CV_NORMAL);  Here the RTOL and ATOL has been tested from 1e-5 to 1e-15, and from 1e-10 to 1e-40, respectively.

Answer (score 6):

From my experience helping a few thousand people debug these things, it's 99% of the time due to an issue with the implementation of the model. Almost always it's some bug in the way the model is written. Because this comes up so often, I wrote a [PSA on the Julia Discourse Forum](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/psa-how-to-help-yourself-debug-differential-equation-solving-issues/62489) and mention details in the [DifferentialEquations.jl FAQ](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/basics/faq/#faq_stability) has a step-by-step process for how to debug it. Since the PSA is very in-depth I won't repeat it all here (please see the link), but the summary is as follows.

Model diverging to infinity, dt<dtmin, etc. are all the same thing. If your model is diverging, then the adaptivity will be decreasing `dt`, and either it will hit Inf first or `dt<dtmin` depending on essentially randomness. So treat it the same as an instability.

1. First and foremost, try different solvers. When doing this, set the tolerance very low to give everything the best chance. Try to use automatic differentiation for the most stable Jacobians, and try to use solvers which are known to be very stable (CVODE_BDF, TRBDF2, Rodas4). If all solvers are diverging in the same way, you can almost surely blame the implementation of `f` as the reason. Usually this is the case, otherwise open an issue.
2. Now that you know `f` is likely the issue, double check your model for sign issues. A good way to do this is to print inside of `f` and watch what happens near the divergence. Anything going really really large in a fishy way? What value is supposed to keep it small? That's the sign error.
3. Double check your assumptions. $u' = -\sqrt{u}$ hits zero in finite time, it does not asymptote. The solver will have an issue with unique of the solution when it hits. Similarly, $u' = u^2 - u$ will diverge to infinity if the initial condition is too large (above 1). The solver is doing the correct thing if it says it's diverging.
4. Double check that `f` is an ODE. If you evaluate the function `f` two times in a row, do you always get the same result? Is there randomness? Are you caching values or "history" between `f` calls? Remember, adaptive ODE solvers do not always go forwards in time, so if you do things like that your history may be the future, and the solution will be dependent on the exact `dt` that you have chosen. The adaptivity measurements will then have trouble to converging to anything since what you have defined is not an ODE, and they will error out with `dt<dtmin`.

And etc. See the full PSA for more details, but that should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

I've often encountered that issue when the system nears a singularity where it starts to "explode", thus requiring very small time steps for the integration error estimate to remain within the prescribed error bounds. These time steps are so small that the physical time $t$ of the simulation is numerically equal to $t+dt$, i.e. the double precision rounding error dominates.

I doubt your problem is linked only to potential stiffness, because CVODE automatically switches between non-stiff (Adams-Moulton) and stiff (BDF) formulae, and in my experience this works quite well.

A good idea would be to look at your solution components and see how they evolve near the time when you get that warning. Most likely some of them are diverging, which may point you in the right direction to find the origin of the problem (e.g. a singularity in your equations if there is one).

Anyway, we need more details to be able to help you further ;) Maybe a simple code that can be run easily and reproduces the error (if you have a Python equivalent of your code for instance).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have checked the output solutions, the data looks fine and not divergent at the step that the warning showed up.

Comment: And can you see what order of magnitude are the time derivatives of each variable ? Maybe some of these become very large, indicating a singularity. Thus the solver must take small time steps to accurately resolve the evolution, and at one point the error estimate is so high that even tiny time steps cannot lead to a sufficiently low interaction error, causing the warning you have seen.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. For the order of time derivatives of each variable, did you mean the t value?

Comment: I mean the values of the time derivatives $dx/dt$ with $x$ being your state vector. Try to see how these evolve near the time when you get the error.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: I think you are right, I have checked the value of those variables, some of them do have very large order of magnitude at a certain time. But I am wondering that how could we set the small time step by ourselves, I read the manual of the CVODE, it seems like that the time step is variable depending on the solving process, and how could we set it by ourselves. Thanks

Comment: In that case, this probably means you are nearing a singularity in your system. What you can do is try to see which equations are yielding large time derivatives. Either this leads you to knowing what the singularity is and which variables cause it, or you may discover an error in your code. If the singularity is real, then I am afraid there is no solution to your problem. Forcing a larger step size would only let the system diverge more quickly, unless you can sort of "go through" the singularity in a single step, but in my experience, this is seldom possible, and not a good approach anyway.

Comment: In my experience, investigating such singularities is always worth your time. It has often led me to identify errors of bugs in my code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will check my equations again and to see where are the bugs. Thank you!